# Is it possible to allocate bigquery slots for different project in a organization level?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have reserved 2000 slots for google bigquery, in organization level, is it possible to allocate fixed number of slots for a project or for a user.
for eg:
     In my 2000 slots, i need to use 500 slots for staging project 500 for data-science project and 1000 slots for analytics project.